# Do bus lines need to connect to bus depots in Cities Skylines?

Tags: cities-skylines

Do my bus lines need to be connected to my bus depot? Like, do they have to have a line from start to finish connected to the depot?

Answer (score 9):

No, the bus depot doesn't need a line. 
When you create a new line, the depot will spawn buses for that line until the number of vehicles for that line is reached.

Comment: Ugh this changes everything

Comment: @Dpeif But having a bus depot close to a route helps with the buses going fast to the route in the morning and fast back to the depot in the evening and not get stuck in traffic.

Comment: @Xander: if one sets different budgets for day and night, that is. Buses will happily drive around without returning to the depot when the number of buses on their line does not change.